# How to make ts-node aware of a namespace declared in a `d.ts` file?

Tags: typescript, namespaces, ts-node, .d.ts, babel-node

I have a `MY_FILE.ts` file like that:

```
const someFunction = (param: MY_NAMESPACE.PARAM) : boolean => { // DO SOMETHING };
```

The param type is accessed through a `namespace` called `MY_NAMESPACE` that I `declare` on a `MY_NAMESPACE.d.ts` file. Like this:

**src/MY_NAMESPACE.d.ts**

```
declare namespace MY_NAMESPACE {
  type PARAM: SOME_TYPE
}
```

I need to run that `MY_FILE.ts` file, which contains a script.

This works fine:

```
npx babel-node src/MY_FILE.ts --extensions ".ts"
```

And this **does not work** (and I expected it to work just fine):

```
npx ts-node src/MY_FILE.ts
```

I get this error: `error TS2503: Cannot find namespace MY_NAMESPACE`

[image]

Note: In my real case, the `MY_NAMESPACE` is called `TYPES`.

How can I make it work with `ts-node` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar issue. The problem was, that `ts-node` is ignoring the `include`-option of the `tsconfig.json` and only following imports/refs in the starting file (see https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#help-my-types-are-missing).

I solved the issue by using the `files` option of `ts-node` in the `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {...},
    "ts-node": {
        "files": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts",
        "./libs/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

There are other solutions for it (triple-slash directives, typeRoots). Just read the link above.